# c malloc pointer to an array of struct

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-management, struct

I am trying to create a pointer to an `array` of structs and pass it to a `function` where I will change values of the struct.

Could someone please explain me why my code seems to not correctly allocate the memory for the `array` as execution of the compiled version fails for **27pixels** if I store **both** `integer` variables in the `struct` whereas it works for 27pixels if I only store **one** `integer` variable?

```
    typedef struct Pixel
    {
        int label;
        int area;
    }Pixelmap;

    int change_pixel(Pixelmap* pixelmap)
    {
         for (x = 0; x < dimx*dimy*dimz; x++)
        {
            pixelmap[x].label = x; /* or malloc and strcpy */
            pixelmap[x].area = 1;
            printf("%i\n",pixelmap[x].label);
        }
        return 1;
    }

    int main()
    {
        Pixelmap *pm;
        pm = malloc(dimx*dimy*dimz * sizeof (struct Pixel));
        change_pixel(&pm);
        printf("End!\n");
        free(pm);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `change_pixel(&pm);`  ====> `change_pixel(pm);` and turn up your compiler warnings as high as they can go. you should have been notified of an incompatible type.

Comment: Perhaps `change_pixel` should be renamed `set_pixel` since the memory allocated by `malloc` is uninitialised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You passed a the address of the pointer to `change_pixel`, but it's expecting the pointer itself. It should be:

```
change_pixel(pm);
```

I'm surprised you didn't get a warning from the compiler about the incorrect type of argument. The argument is declared `Pixelmap*`, but you passed `Pixelmap**`.

Comment: thanks a lot. i will pay more attention to warnings next time!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is a typo but you allocate

```
sizeof(struct Pixel)
```

it should be

```
sizeof(struct Pixelmap)
```

as in

```
pm = malloc(dimx*dimy*dimz * sizeof (struct Pixelmap));
```